# How am I doing for an old guy

Tags: machine, rowing-machine

I just started two weeks ago after laying around too much 
I finished 10,000 meters in 1:0245
Then                                     57:30
Then                                      56:45
Yesterday.                              54:43

61 years old.  Seven stents
5:9
225lbs
I Kayak in the ocean on a five mile course about six to eight times a month in the warm weather

Answer (score 2):

[Concept2](http://www.concept2.com/), the lead manufacturer of rowing machines, provides free access to an online [logbook with rankings](http://log.concept2.com/).  It's a global community of rowing athletes, fitness enthusiasts, and everyday people who like using the machine for exercise.  The site offers encouragement, workout routines, and “challenges” to keep your fitness experience fresh.  If you'd like to compare yourself to others, you should create a **free** profile on their site and upload your results.  The site will rank your workouts based on your profile.  However, it will not take into consideration any physical or other conditions that may affect your performance.

If you are using a Concept2 rower, I would encourage you to take advantage of the data capture capabilities of the machine.  The [Performance Monitor](http://www.concept2.com/indoor-rowers/performance-monitors) can easily track your workouts allowing you to keep a history of your progress.

[image]

There are two basic ways to upload your results using the PM.  If you can, I'd suggest you purchase ($6.50) a “logcard” to record your workouts.  There are many card readers available on line that will connect to your PC to allow you to upload your results.

[image]

**EDIT**:

G_H's comment reminded me that there's an additional way to record your progress with the C2 rower.  Some of their PM's are equipped with Bluetooth capabilities.  If you load their app on your phone, you can track your workouts to the phone and upload them later from the same app.

Comment: I can't believe how often I've warmed up on a C2 and never really paid attention to the fact that it has a card reader...

Comment: @G_H Please see my edit.